# Broadcast Receiver Incoming Call (Getting two times incoming number)

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, incoming-call

Why am I getting the incoming number twice? With the outgoing detail it is properly working, but it gets only once but I  don't know what happens to incoming detail. Can anyone help me?

```
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Log.d("APP", "ACTION:" + intent.getAction());
    //this.context = context;
    final String stringExtra = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);

    if (Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL.equals(intent.getAction())){
        //outgoing call
        number=intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
        Log.i("tag", "Outgoing number : " +number);
        currentDateTimeString = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date());
        Log.i("tag", "Date :" + currentDateTimeString);
       //doSaveCallRecord(1);
        Log.i("tag", "USER ID :" + context.getSharedPreferences("APPLICATION",Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getString(UserConstants.ID,null)+"");
    }
    if (TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING.equals(stringExtra)) {
        final String incomingNumber = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
        Log.d("APP", "incoming,ringing:" + incomingNumber);
        //doSaveCallRecord(0);
    }
}
```

```
<receiver android:name=".MyCallReceiver" > 
      <intent-filter> 
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL"/> 
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"/> 
      </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: please provide the code for sendBroadcast

Comment: Please, post your AndroidManifest as well, as any Logcat (that logged a call for instance). Finally, try to describe an example condition that duplicates the desired and undesired effect. Also, the described event is likely two or more receivers with the same broadcast event. Show where you registered the receivers (dinamically and statically)

Comment: <receiver android:name=".MyCallReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"/>

            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code for checking incoming number to specific number:

```
 @Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
    TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    telephony.listen(new PhoneStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
            super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
            if(incomingNumber.contains("CHECKING NUMBER")){
                AudioManager audio_mngr = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                audio_mngr.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
            }
            System.out.println("incomingNumber : "+incomingNumber);
        }
    },PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
}
```

Comment: Can we maintain two separate file of broadcast receiver. one for outgoing call and one for incoming call?

Comment: i am still getting incoming no more than two times